# Detect a specific pattern between rows

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
tibble(id = c(1000, 2000, 2000, NA, 2000, NA, 1000, 2000))
```

The data come ordered like this and I would like to add an indicator yes/no if an id is preceded by the same id and has a row with NA in between. (I don't care about other ids in between as long as there is at least one NA between the two ids.)

How can I achieve this (preferably using dplyr)?

The solution should look like this:

```
     id outcome
  <dbl> <chr>  
1  1000 no     
2  2000 no     
3  2000 no     
4    NA no     
5  2000 yes    
6    NA no     
7  1000 yes    
8  2000 yes
```

Comment: Why does row 7's outcome is "yes"? it is not preceded by the same id.

Comment: It is preceded (with a lag of 6 rows) by the same id and there is an NA value in between. The outcome should be "yes" independent of other ids in between.

Comment: Should all NAs be "no" or is there an inverse rule for NAs?

Comment: All NAs should be "no".

Answer (score 0):

`yes` when `id` is duplicated (second or more occurrence of a same value), not `NA` (`complete.cases`) and after the first `NA` (`cumany(is.na(id))`).

```r
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% 
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(cumany(is.na(id)) & duplicated(id) & complete.cases(id), "yes", "no"))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
     id outcome
  <dbl> <chr>  
1  1000 no     
2  2000 no     
3  2000 no     
4    NA no     
5  2000 yes    
6    NA no     
7  1000 yes    
8  2000 yes
```

Comment: This works for the sample data provided and almost perfectly for my data. However, one condition for "yes" is that there is an NA value **between** the ids. How can I make it work in the following case?

`tibble(id = c(NA, 1000, 2000, 2000, NA, 2000, NA, 1000, 2000))`

In this case "outcome" for the id value in the fourth row (2000) is "yes" although it is only preceded by an NA and not preceded by an NA **and** the id. It should be "no".